# Cinnamon Installation Errors

Tags: cinnamon

I wish to install Cinnamon on my laptop. I have run the command to install Cinnamon but the download does not complete. This same problem has happened when trying to update Ubuntu and Lubuntu.

Listed below is the reject details. I am resident in NZ but have no clue why the error message appears. I have changed the download site to "international" and the `nz.archive.com` site does not exist.

Your help would be gratefully received.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/maverick-backports/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
:~$ sudo apt-get install cinnamon cinnamon-session cinnamon-settings
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package cinnamon
E: Unable to locate package cinnamon-session
E: Unable to locate package cinnamon-settings
```

After following Alaa's answer, I get these errors:

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch ..ppa.launchpad.net/merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch....ppa.launchpad.net/merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 cinnamon : Depends: libgjs0-libmozjs185-1.0 but it is not installable
            Depends: libgjs0c (>= 1.34.0) but 1.32.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
            Depends: cinnamon-control-center but it is not going to be installed or
                     gnome-control-center but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: gir1.2-gkbd-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: gnome-themes-standard but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: nemo but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: cinnamon-screensaver but it is not going to be installed
            Recommends: gir1.2-gjsdbus-1.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? 10.10?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 12.04 and use Lubuntu. I reverted back to Ubuntu to try and load Cinnamon.

Comment: Check my answer.

Comment: Hi Robin! You've posted your reply to me as an answer to your question. You shouldn't do that. Instead, you should update your question with the errors you got. At Ask Ubuntu, you can edit your question by clicking the `edit` link right underneath the text of your question. After you do that, you should then comment on my answer (using the `add comment` button right underneath my answer) telling me that you've edited your question so that I get a notification =). But anyways, I have already edited your question for you and included the errors.

Comment: From the output of that 404 error, it says `ppa.launchpad.net/merlwiz79/cinnamon-ppa/ubuntu/dists/quantal`, which means you're running Ubuntu Quantal (Ubuntu 12.10), but you said you're running 12.04. Which one is it exactly? Because this makes my "Steps to reset your repositories" part in my answer useless. So which Ubuntu did you install? Also, since you say that you've reverted back to Ubuntu, I assume that you reinstalled, so why don't you just install the latest Ubuntu (13.04) instead? If you install it, you'll be able to do `sudo apt-get install cinnamon` without additional steps.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you actually have two things to worry about:

1. Your sources are messed up, because they're pointing to Ubuntu 10.10 repositories, which don't exist anymore because the support for that version ended (and that's why you're getting the `404 Not Found` errors).
2. After doing a [quick search on the `cinnamon` package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=cinnamon&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all), it's only available for 13.04 in the repositories. To install it on 12.04, you'll need to do some extra steps to get the PPA (the repository) that provides it for 12.04.

Here's what you should do:

## Steps to reset your repositories:

1. `cd /etc/apt && sudo cp sources.list sources.list.back1`

   - Taking a backup of your current `sources.list` file, because we're going to edit it.
2. `gksu gedit sources.list`

   - Opening up `sources.list` to edit it.
3. When the text editor opens up, delete everything inside the file, and copy everything from [**here**](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6131463/) and paste it in the file.

   - These are the proper repositories for 12.04, using the New Zealand .
4. Save and close the text editor.
5. `sudo apt-get update`

   - This will update your packages index with the new, correct sources we added.

## Steps to get and install cinnamon on 12.04

1. `sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable && sudo apt-get update`

   - This adds the PPA that contains `cinnamon` for 12.04 and updates the package index.
2. `sudo apt-get install cinnamon`

   - This should successfully install `cinnamon`.